# connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, sockets, asyncsocket, socketexception

Hi I had a working middle-ware program using C#. The program sends some request to a website and pulls data back from there . Now I am getting an error and I know since the website URL has been changed .

before the URL was : ip:port
but now the URL has been changed to : ip:port/NugaWeb

How can I change my program to request to go to the new URL . Probably adding something to a buffer , am not sure if someone can help .

Error :

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer)
   at myRfid.ConnSocket.getResponse(Int32 protocol, String sendString) in d:\Birth_DayTestNewServer\myRfid\ConnSocket.cs:line 87}
```

Connection.cs

```
class ConnSocket
    {
        public const int OVERHIT_ADD_USER = 100;
        public const int OVERHIT_GET_AVERAGE_OF_AGE= 101;
        public const int OVERHIT_WRITE_TEST_RESULT = 102;
        public const int OVERHIT_USER_LIST = 103;
        public const int OVERHIT_USER_SEX= 105;

        public const string HEADER="FF00";
        public const string TAILER="/$/$";
        private Socket clientSocket = null;
        //public static string ip = "121.158.41.217";

        public static string ip = "165.132.221.47";

        private byte[] receiveData;

        private void connection()
        {

            try
            {
                receiveData=new byte[4096];

                clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);





            //clientSocket.Connect(ip, 8090);
            clientSocket.Connect(ip, 8080);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }


        public string getResponse(int protocol, string sendString)
        {
            string sendMsg = "";
            string recMsg = "";
            byte[] send = null;
            byte[] rec = null;
            connection();
            try
            {
                Encoding korean = Encoding.GetEncoding("euc-kr");
                Encoding enc = Encoding.ASCII;
                rec=new byte[1024];
                //serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();


                sendMsg = HEADER + "&" + protocol + "&" + sendString + TAILER;             //Step3 :sendMsg=""   
                send = new byte[korean.GetBytes(sendMsg).Length];       //Step4 : sendMsg = "FF00&105&eecb0b7e000104e0/$/$"     sendMsg becomes "FF00&105&/$/$" and then becomes "FF00&101&eecb0b7e000104e0&28/$/$"  and then "FF00&101&&28/$/$"



                send=korean.GetBytes(sendMsg);

                //i tried adding a check on sendMsg here
                if (sendMsg == "FF00&105&/$/$")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Card not placed !! Place the card and please try again  ");
                    return null;

                    //System.Environment.Exit(0);
                }

                clientSocket.Send(send);

                int recLen = 0;
                recLen=clientSocket.Receive(rec);

                recMsg = korean.GetString(rec, 0, recLen);



                //sw.Write(send);           
                /*
                rec = new byte[1024];
                rec=korean.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());
                */
                /*
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    recMsg=recMsg+sr.ReadLine();
                }
                 * */



            }


           catch (Exception ex)                                          
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }


                /*i tried this 

            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                if (e.SocketErrorCode == WouldBlock)
                {
                    m_socket.Blocking = true;
                    m_socket.Send(buffer, bufferSize, SocketFlags.None);
                    m_socket.Blocking = false;
                }
            }*/


            finally
            {


                if (clientSocket != null)
                {
                    clientSocket.Close(); clientSocket = null;
                }

            }
            return recMsg;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are you failing?

Comment: In the getResponse connection block . maybe like I said I know the problem ... I need to send request and response to 165.132.221.47:8080/NugaWeb . But the current program is sending to 165.132.221.47:8080. I would like to know how can i append "/NugaWeb" ....

Comment: You are mixing two protocols, IP and HTTP.  IP:PORT is a simple connection between sockets done in `clientSocket.Connect(ip, 8080);` while `ip:port/NugaWeb` is something related to client / server at the HTTP level, which doesn't appear here.

Comment: @mins: I understand your point . You mean I will have to change the whole program to use HTTP instead of sockets now ?

Comment: The TCP connection is established by `Socket#Connect(ip, port)`. It seems to work. Then you should send something using this TCP connection (e.g. a HTTP GET request.), you seem to manage this in `clientSocket.Send(send);`, but you do this manually (is that HTTP?). The connection is reset by the server at this higher level, which in turn leads to the TCP server to reset its own level, creating the error in the client at the TCP level. So you should look at what you do in the `send` and why.

Comment: Are you getting back as the status 200 Done from the http message?  The IP address hasn't changed.  Instead the Root of the HTTP as changed.  Without know more about the error I can't determine if anything needs to be changed.